# Nodal voltage after a resistor

Tags: diodes, nodal-analysis

I know this is an extremely trivial question especially after studying thus far, however, I  still can't wrap my head around how we are supposed to calculate the nodal voltage depicted below:
[image]

In this case B, I am supposed to figure out whether or not the diode D2 with a threshold voltage of 1V is activated. In order for it to be so, the voltage across the diode must be greater than 1V. In a simple series series circuit B would obviously be 0V but I can't figure out the voltage of B in this circuit to see whether or not D2 is active or not. I know ohm's law cannot be used here, any help is appreciated. Would B just simply be 2V because the resistor only limits current?

Comment: If you think to use nodal analysis , think again!

Comment: Because the V1 is lower than V2. You need to determine the voltage at point A first. We can see that the voltage at point A (D1 off) will be around 3V if D1 is the ideal diode or 2.5V if D1 Vf =1V . Therefore there is no way for the D2 diode to conduct any current .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First consider the circuit with V1 disconnected, then you can calculate the Voltage at A.  If adding V2 results in a forward voltage existing on D2 then D2 will allow current to flow.  Once you know whether or not D2 is conducting, you can recalculate the voltage ms and currents.